# Prove $\operatorname{csch}^{-1} x = \ln \left(\frac {1}{x} + \frac {\sqrt{1+x^2}}{|x|}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Prove $\operatorname{csch} ^{-1} x = \ln \left(\frac {1}{x} + \frac {\sqrt{1+x^2}}{|x|}\right)$

I can only derive $\operatorname{csch} ^{-1} x = \ln \left(\frac {1}{x} + \frac {\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right)$, but the answer is the above involving absolute value.

Help me to prove it.

Comment: What happens with your formula when $x<0$?

Comment: Did you happen to do $\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{x^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$?

Answer (score 1):

That absolute value comes from the fact that:

$$
\sqrt{x^2}=|x|
$$
And not:

$$
\sqrt{x^2}=x
$$

As $x$ can be positive or negative but the square root is always positive that's why you need to have the absolute value.
You originally had:

$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{|x|}
$$

Comment: How did you derive the above formula? I derive it by quadratic equation and its quadratic root formula, and there is no idea of $\sqrt {(1+ \frac{1}{x^2})}$.

Comment: No I just explained that part and wasnt deriving the formula. Plus when I actually tried to derive the formula on paper that square root appeared and then I knew why there should be an absolute value